# How do I make a paraphrase generation using BERT/ GPT-2

Tags: nlp, gpt-2

I am trying hard to understand how to make a paraphrase generation using BERT/GPT-2. I cannot understand how do I make it. Could you please provide me with any resources where I will be able to make a paraphrase generation model?
**"The input would be a sentence and the output would be a paraphrase of the sentence"**

Answer (score 8):

Here is my recipe for training a paraphraser:

1. Instead of BERT (encoder only) or GPT (decoder only) use a seq2seq model with both encoder and decoder, such as T5, BART, or Pegasus. I suggest using  [the multilingual T5 model](https://huggingface.co/google/mt5-base) that was pretrained for 101 languages. If you want to load embeddings for your own language (instead of using all 101), you can follow [this recipe](https://cointegrated.medium.com/how-to-adapt-a-multilingual-t5-model-for-a-single-language-b9f94f3d9c90).
2. Find a corpus of paraphrases for your language and domain. For English, ParaNMT, PAWS, and QQP are good candidates. A corpus called [Tapaco](https://huggingface.co/datasets/tapaco), extracted from Tatoeba, is a paraphrasing corpus that covers 73 languages, so it is a good starting point if you cannot find a paraphrase corpus for your language.
3. Fine-tune your model on this corpus. The code can be something like this:

```py
import torch
from transformers import T5ForConditionalGeneration, T5Tokenizer
# use here a backbone model of your choice, e.g. google/mt5-base
backbone_model = 'cointegrated/rut5-base-multitask' 
model = T5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(backbone_model)
tokenizer = T5Tokenizer.from_pretrained(backbone_model)
model.cuda();
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(params=[p for p in model.parameters() if p.requires_grad], lr=1e-5)

# todo: load the paraphrasing corpus and define the get_batch function

for i in range(100500):
    xx, yy = get_batch(mult=mult)
    x = tokenizer(xx, return_tensors='pt', padding=True).to(model.device)
    y = tokenizer(yy, return_tensors='pt', padding=True).to(model.device)
    # do not force the model to predict pad tokens
    y.input_ids[y.input_ids==0] = -100
    loss = model(
        input_ids=x.input_ids,
        attention_mask=x.attention_mask,
        labels=y.input_ids,
        decoder_attention_mask=y.attention_mask,
        return_dict=True
    ).loss
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    optimizer.zero_grad()

model.save_pretrained('my_paraphraser')
tokenizer.save_pretrained('my_paraphraser')
```

A more complete version of this code can be found [in this notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1DGeF190gJ3DjRFQiwhFuZalp427iqJNQ?usp=sharing).

After the training, the model can be used in the following way:

```py
from transformers import pipeline
pipe = pipeline(task='text2text-generation', model='my_paraphraser')
print(pipe('Here is your text'))
# [{'generated_text': 'Here is the paraphrase or your text.'}]
```

If you want your paraphrases to be more diverse, you can control the generation procress using [arguments](https://huggingface.co/transformers/_modules/transformers/generation_utils.html#GenerationMixin.generate) like

```
print(pipe(
    'Here is your text', 
    encoder_no_repeat_ngram_size=3,  # make output different from input
    do_sample=True,  # randomize
    num_beams=5,  # try more options
    max_length=128,  # longer texts
))
```

Enjoy!

Comment: can we create para phrase tool in English with T5 ? I'm new to Python.

Comment: @Sourav. Yes, we can. The code above is already doing it; you need only to plug an English paraphrase dataset into it. 
But first you probably need to learn some Python :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use T5 paraphrasing for generating paraphrases

Comment: This is not a proper answer. Elaborate more on this. How it solves the OP's problem.

Answer (score -1):

whatever , paraphrase you got from this above code that is coming in sequence like your text = "kohli a indian cricketer is " after paraphrasing it is coming in sequence like "kohli is a indian cricketer" mean i want SOV(subject verb object ).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).